# TypeError: Sprite.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pygame, typeerror

Here is my class:

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __int__(self, position, surface, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = surface
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=position)
```

Here is my code:

```
for layer in tmx_data.visible_layers:
    if hasattr(layer, 'data'):
        for x, y, surf in layer.tiles():
            pos = (x*128, y*128)
            Tile(position=pos, surface=surf, groups=sprite_group)
```

For some reason I am getting the error:

```
Tile(position=pos, surface=surf, groups=sprite_group)
TypeError: Sprite.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position'
```

**Any fixes? You will need to import pygame and pyTMX modules to test this.**

*What I have tried: *
I have tried adding all the parameters in my child function to my parent function, writing super(Tile, self), and doing Tile(pos, surf, groups). I have checked my spelling over and over again and ChatGPT keeps saying that I intialized it wrong, quote: "The error you're encountering is caused by a typo in your Tile class. In the constructor, you have defined the method name as **int** instead of **init**. Due to this typo, the superclass Sprite is not being properly initialized, resulting in the error when you try to create an instance of Tile with the position argument." That makes no sense.

This is the code that I am using: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6xqCwblyiw. You can find his github here (https://github.com/clear-code-projects/Tiled), navigate to code directory, then tiled_code.py, and you will find that my code is practically identical to his.

Thank you so much for your time, man I really need this for a project due soon.

Comment: You have a typo in `Tile` class. You have `__int__` instead of `__init__`. How is ChatGPT explanation not making sense?

Comment: Oh my god I did not see that. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Since you haven't technically defined `__init__` in `Tile` class it's not run at initialisation and then the superclass has no idea what to do with `position` and `surface`